# Cannot run an "initialise" function in Puppet after installing package

Tags: puppet, aide

OK I have been working on puppet for 12 months, I am deploying a manifest to install the "aide" package, but I cannot see any option to trigger the 'initialise' of aide after install of the package. There is no "notify" function on the "package" directive. How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

The `notify` parameter is a metaparameter and can be applied to any resource. Source:

https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/lang_relationships.html#refreshing-and-notification
https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/metaparameter.html

Typically, the ordering is as follows:

```
class myclass {

  package { 'myapp':
    ensure => present,
  }

  file { '/etc/myapp.conf':
    ensure  => file,
    ...
    notify  => Service['myapp'],
    require => Package['myapp'],
  }

  service { 'myapp':
    ensure => running,
    enable => true,
  }
}
```